# TypeScript error number is not assignable

Tags: typescript

I am writing a reducer and I want RESET to do `state.count = 0`.  However, this gives me an error that `number is not assignable to type CounterState`.

Here is my code:

```
export interface CounterState {
  count: number;
};

const initialState: CounterState = {
  count: 0
};

export default function counter(state = initialState, action: Action): CounterState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.INCREMENT:
      return assign({}, state, {
        count: state.count + 1
      });
    case TYPES.DECREMENT:
      return assign({}, state, {
          count : state.count - 1
        });
    case TYPES.RESET:
      //error here
      return state.count=0;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am using lodash's assign function.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified the return type of your function as CounterState, but for the reset case, you are trying to return a number (`state.count=0` evaluates to the number on the right, so you are returning 0)

Instead you should return a state object either using the initialState constant

```
case Types.RESET:
    return initialState;
```

Or using the assign as well here, if you have other properties on the state, you wish to preserve

```
case Types.RESET:
    return assign({}, state, {
      count : 0
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You function output parameter is **CounterState**, but you are trying to return a number here:

```
return state.count=0;
```

just replace it with

```
state.count = 0;
return state;
```